# What does the tag [time] mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Stack Overflow has a tag [time](/questions/tagged/time) which is used with several related meanings:

- Obtaining the current time, or both date and time (e.g. with the `time` function in C)
- Formatting or parsing the time of day
- Measuring the running time of a program (including the `time` utility on unix-like systems)

This tag was included in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012 with reservations

> not sure if this is a good tag, the wiki is a copy/paste from Wikipedia and it can't stand on its own

so we need to discuss it. (And please remove it from the list in the meantime, so that zealous users don't start removing it willy-nilly.)

Comment: You should also add the [tag:date] tag to that.

Comment: @dunsmoreb [tag:date] seems less broad: it's always about operations on dates, one way or another.